# Scope: Using Variable Defined in a Function

Tags: php, wordpress, variables, global-variables, scope

I have a function in a functions.php file that defines certain variables:

```
add_action( 'the_post', 'paginate_slide' );

function paginate_slide( $post ) {

    global $pages, $multipage, $numpages;

    if( is_single() && get_post_type() == 'post' ) {

    $multipage = 1;
    $id = get_the_ID();
    $custom = array();
    $pages = array();
    $i = 1;

    foreach( get_post_custom_keys() as $key )
        if ( false !== strpos( $key, 'slide' ) )
            $custom[$key] = get_post_meta( $id, $key, true);

    while( isset( $custom["slide{$i}-title"] ) ) {

        $page = '';
        $tzTitle = $custom["slide{$i}-title"];
        $tzImage = $custom["slide{$i}-image"];
        $tzDesc = $custom["slide{$i}-desc"];
        $tzEmbed = $custom["slide{$i}-embed"];

        $page = "<h2>{$tzTitle}</h2><img src='{$tzImage}' />";
        $pages[] = $page;
        $i++;
    }

    $numpages = count( $pages );
    }
}
```

I'd like to output some of these variables in a template.php file like so: `<?php echo $tzDesc; ?>` but I can't seem to get it to work.  From what I understand about the [variables scope](http://php.net/manual/en/language.variables.scope.php), in order to call these variables in another place I need to define them within the global scope and call them as global in this function like I did the `$pages, $multipage, $numpages;`.  That should allow me to plug those variables in where I need them.  The problem is when I take them out of the function and define them above within the global scope the entire function stops working.

How do I need to structure this so I can call `<?php echo $tzDesc; ?>` anywhere in the site and have it echo the defined info?

I don't know if this matters but this is on a WordPress site.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you want to use `<?php echo $tzDesc; ?>` anyway, you would need to define `$tzDesc` as a global variable. However, I don't recommend doing so as global variables are considered *poor* programming practice.

A better solution would be to have the `paginate_slide()` add `$tzDesc` (and other values) to the `$post` object. That way you have access to these variables anytime you call `the_post()`. If you go this route, be sure to namespace you variables:

```
$post->ns_tzDesc = $tzDesc;
```

Comment: Adding them to the $post object sounds like a much better solution.  How would I do that?  To be honest, I'm not sure where $post is defined.  If it helps, this is on a Wordpress site.

Comment: Very similar to how you are modifying `$pages` - `$pages[] = $page;` See the update.

Comment: I tried that and it said `Fatal error: Cannot use object of type stdClass as array in...`

Comment: That works a little better but it looses the incremental nature of the `$i` variable which specifies which data to display based on which page is being displayed (slide1-embed on page 1, slide2-embed on page 2...).  Doing it this way appears to only retrieved the information that is meant for the last page and displays it on every page.  How can I maintain the incremental nature of this data?